# How to check if selected text in html already has a class?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a function that takes a selected piece of text and highlights it by adding the  tag. It highlights the text but if I click the highlight button again, the text disappears. Instead, I'd just want the text to go back to being un-highlighted. Anyone have suggestions how I could go about doing this?

```js
  highLightText() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log('this is the selection: ', selection);
    var selection_text = selection.toString();

    var mark = document.createElement('mark');

    mark.textContent = selection_text;

    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(mark);
  }
```

My idea was to somehow check if the selected text from var selection has an element named mark in it and if it does, don't continue with the rest of the function. I'm just not exactly sure how to implement it.

Comment: _"has a class named mark"_, you mean is inside an element named `mark`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes exactly, my bad on the wording.

Comment: How about checking whether or not the `highlighter` element already exists? And if it exists, just unwrap its contents.

Comment: BTW, I wonder don't you have a problem related to the text changing its place when 'copypasted' from one text node into another - described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818759/why-does-text-splittext-affect-layout) of mine.

Comment: @raina77ow, that can easily be solved by running [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) on the parent element of the text nodes, this will merge all sibling text nodes.

Comment: Not sure I understand your advice. When a word is to be highlighted, the corresponding text node containing it will be split - once or twice, depending on whether or not the word is on the edge. My point is that split causes a relayout. Yes, `normalize` is the way to go when highlight is dropped; but when it's in place, `normalize` just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @raina77ow, oh I thought you were simply talking about the text nodes after the drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the node that is currently selected by using the Selection's [anchorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorNode) or [focusNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusNode) and from there get the parent element of the text.

```
var parent = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
```

From there is it just a matter of checking it's [nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) property to see if it is `mark`.

```
parent.nodeName == "MARK" //nodeName is uppercase
```

After that just replace the mark element with the text node and call [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) on the grand parent element to make sure any adjacent text nodes get merged

```
let grandParent = parent.parentElement; 
parent.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(parent.textContent));
grandParent.normalize();
```

This will do all the text in the mark element and not just the selected text of a mark, for that you will have to modify the code if that was the intention.

Demo (hit any key after making a selection)

```js
function highLightText() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var parent = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;
  var selection_text = selection.toString();

  if (parent.nodeName == "MARK") {
    let grandParent = parent.parentElement;
    parent.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(parent.textContent));
    grandParent.normalize();
    return;
  }

  var mark = document.createElement('mark');

  mark.textContent = selection_text;

  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(mark);
}
document.addEventListener('keyup',highLightText);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Test one two three</div>
  <div>Test four five six</div>
  <div>Test seven eight nine</div>
  <div>Test ten eleven twelve</div>
</div>
```